# Suggestions on Data Exploration/Visualization from the Browser of a table of 10,000 rows and 5 columns?

Tags: jquery, filtering, tablesorter, data-visualization

Is my dataset too large for people to explore from the browser?

The size of the `json_data.js` is 550KB.

Dimension are 5 columns and 10,000 lines. (3 columns of words, 1 of dates, and 1 of integers)

Basically I have 10,000 of these lines `"Id|Activity_Title|Location|Start|Duration"`

I had initially hoped to use 2 jquery plugins, [tablefilter](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/simpleFilter) and [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), but they make my browser freeze with this large dataset (though they have worked great with smaller datasets).

Can anyone suggest alternative ways or approaches (or plugins) to summarize and visualize datasets of 10,000 rows and 5 columns using just javascript and the browser.

Comment: can you try pagination and request the remaining results only when you click next or page2 or 3 like that instead of loading everything upfront.

Comment: what do you think about pagination logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to handle this is through pagination, but that's not the best approach.

The best thing to do is to provide a smart initial filter for the data plus tools for the user to easily expand or narrow the filter.  It's pointless to show the user 10,000 rows.  But generally you can project based on your application's business rules what rows the user really wants to see.  Are they most likely to want the most recent records?  Or maybe most recent in a particular location?  Or some other common criteria?  The better you can provide them with a smart initial list, the better user experience they'll have.

After that initial list is available, give them tools to expand or narrow the list further.  When they do eventually get a list that is too big to show (usually no more than 50 rows per page, often 20) then use paged data to only show a small subset of rows at a time.